# Django (mod_wsgi) - HttpBasicAuthentication using view decorator - AttributeError

Tags: django, apache, http, authentication, decorator

I'm writing a small app. I wish to use a view decorator I found.
This here is [the snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/243/), and this is [a post describing its usage](http://www.arnebrodowski.de/blog/508-Django,-mod_wsgi-and-HTTP-Authentication.html).
I have an Apache server (2.2) running, and Django is up-to-date.
I've decorated a view, and when trying to GET it, an AttributeError occurs:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost/redb/test/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'redb_app')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')

Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  187.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py" in process_response
  109.         if response.status_code == 404:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /redb/test/
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

This is how I'm using it:

```
@logged_in_or_basicauth
def test_handler(request):
    return HttpResponse("Test!")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decorator takes an argument, so you must call the decorator, even if you do not provide the argument `realm` and let it default to "".

```
@logged_in_or_basicauth()
def test_handler(request):
    return HttpResponse("Test!")
```